# Move XSI schema definition

Tags: xml, jaxb

Using JAXB i generate this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsi:beanView xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" editable="false" name="aaaaa" scrollWidth="0" xsi:schemaLocation="">
    <columns>
        <column>
            <code>aaaaa</code>
            <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        </column>
    </columns>
    <queryFilter xsi:nil="true"/>
</xsi:beanView>
```

with

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BeanView.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "");
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);            
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(beanView, System.out);
```

Is it possible to move the definition of schema xsi="http://www.w3..." in the first XML TAG and how? 
or is it possible to write and read the XML including null value without this schema definition?

I try this

```
@XmlSchema ( 
    xmlns = { 
      @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix="xsi", namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    },    
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    attributeFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED
  )
```

with no sucess the result still

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<beanView xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" editable="false" name="aaaaa" scrollWidth="0" xsi:schemaLocation="">
    <columns>
        <column>
            <code>aaaaa</code>
            <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        </column>
    </columns>
    <queryFilter xsi:nil="true"/>
</beanView>
```

Comment: Why to you think this is necessary?

Comment: to simplify the edit and the readability if the config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xsi` prefix needs to be declared at or above the node at which it is being used.  Since the `xsi:schemaLocation` location attribute is in the `beanView` element it needs to be defined there.

Also you currently have the `beanView` element in the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace which is wrong.  It should be in your own namespace or no namespace.

---

### UPDATE

> i just want to generate bean to xml and xml to bean without this xsi
>   url, and with xsi:nil values

To remove the `xmlns:xsi` declaration from your use case you need to do the following:

- Remove the following call that is causing the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute being set:

  ```
  jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "");
  ```
- Make sure you don't have any properties annotated with `@XmlElement(nillable=true)` this is causing the `xsi:nil` attribute to be set.  Removing the `nillable=true` aspect will cause `null` to be represented as an absent element.

  - http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html
- Your root element appears to be namespace qualified as well.  You need to be sure that the `@XmlRootElement` (or `@XmlElementDecl`) annotations don't have this namespace, or that it isn't set on the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation (this would be on a `package-info` class).

Comment: IN XHTML JSF the shema are defined in the first TAG like <html xmlns:h='http://java.sun.com/jsf/html' >

Comment: @user3252285 - The `xmlns:xsi` is in the first tag (`beanView`).  The XML declaration on the first line is not a tag.  The following will help with JAXB and namespaces:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Thank i already take a look at your blog wich is very clear, is there a way to tell the marchal and the unmarchal to use the shema implicitly?

Comment: @user3252285 - For namespace qualification (this done via the `@XmlSchema` annotation, for `xsi:schemaLocation` this is done with the `Marshaller`.

Comment: So what is the solution adding @XmlShema to the beanView ?

Comment: @user3252285 - Ultimately are you trying to namespace qualify your XML (like `<html xmlns:h='java.sun.com/jsf/html'>`) or add the `schemaLocation` attribute?

Comment: i just want to generate bean to xml and xml to bean without this xsi url, and with xsi:nil values

Comment: @user3252285 - I have updated my answer with some information that should help.

Comment: Thank you, but again, i need to keep nillable=true, because i want that the configuration file contain all properties, even empty ones

Comment: I think that i must hack this during the reading and the writing of the Stream with some replaceAll..., wich is not very nice

Comment: @user3252285 - Not sure why you feel you need to hack anything.  You currently have metadata that is causing the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` to be brought in.  You simply need to remove this metadata.  If you can't remove the metadata then that namespace should be there.